# Why use emitter current from DC response in calculations?

Tags: bjt

I am reading a textbook about BJT AC analysis. When finding Re I wondered why the value of the DC response is used for the emitter current.

I assumed that when an AC signal is applied, Ib is not constant, so Ic and the emitter current are also not constant, and Re is not constant, but in my text book they use the emitter current from the DC response. Why?

[Picture of textbook I read](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1l0LtoeIMcPsCqSXzgo5yJQJfVb3g60K7wAzp0tNFSP8/edit?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: BJTs are ***highly*** non-linear devices. This makes finding closed solution equations very difficult. A way to handle that is to first do a DC analysis (through iteration) to work out their operating point and then use the differental (a simple, flat, local slope, which is assumed to be a linear tangent line to the highly non-linear I/V curve) at that DC operating point as an assumption about what happens with slight (AC) changes around that point. This makes it a linear (instead of non-linear) solution, which is ***lots*** easier to work out.

Comment: So when you read "BJT small-signal model" or "BJT AC model" you should understand this to mean "highly simplified local-slope near operating point" model. It's what happens when you take the fuller, far more complex Ebers-Moll model or Gummel-Poon model and apply differential methods to linearize them around some assumed operating point (that you have to otherwise figure out, first.) This is also why the DC solution is first required, so as to figure out where it is on the highly non-linear I/V curve the circuit resides before taking the differential to find the local tangent slope.

Answer (score 5):

In "small signal AC" analysis, you assume that the amplitude of the AC signal is negligibly small compared to the DC bias current. Therefore the AC signal doesn't significantly perturb the DC bias point nor the parameters of the transistor. This is called 'linearizing' the system - you approximate the device characteristics (beta, re etc. ) as constant for a given bias point.

Answer (score 1):

When Re (the external emitter resistor) is not large compared to re (the intrinsic emitter resistance), the variation in Ie (the emitter current) as the input moves up and down causes distortion of the output signal. That is to say the variation in the value of re, away from its value calculated using the dc bias current value, causes distortion.

When the input signal swings positive, Ie increases reducing re causing increased amplitude negative-going output peaks. When the input swings negative, Ie reduces increasing re causing reduced amplitude positive-going output peaks.

This distortion effect is worst for a grounded emitter amplifier when all the emitter resistance is by-passed.

The distortion effect caused by the variation of re with signal amplitude also gets worse as input signal amplitude is increased. This is because, the higher the amplitude, the larger the variation in Ie and so the larger the variation in the value of re compared to the fixed value of Re.

I would suggest that Fig.25 in your link is not a practical circuit and that in reality a common emitter amplifier would never actually be built with that configuration.

Consider a practical design as shown below...

[image: Amplifier]

In the above more practical version, Re2 would be added to raise Ve to a significant voltage (let's say 1 V) above ground in order to provide stable dc biasing. To maximise gain, Re2 would be by-passed by C2 and Re1 would be made equal to zero ohms. In this configuration we have what is effectively a grounded (to ac) emitter and there is no negative feedback.

Feedback factor = 1 + loop gain = 1 + (RE1/re) = 1 which means no negative feedback. The feedback factor is also equal to dVin/dVbe = 1. In this situation the distortion caused by the variation in re (as Vin swings up and down) is high. Increasing the amplitude of Vin will increase the re variation (as Vin swings up and down) further increasing the distortion.

To reduce the distortion we increase the value of Re1 above the value of 0 ohms. Increasing Re1 increases negative feedback and reduces the variation in re (as Vin swings up and down). As I said before, the feedback factor = 1 + Re1/re and so increasing the value of Re1 increases negative feedback which reduces distortion.

As Re1 is increased upwards above 0 ohms, at first the negative feedback increases rapidly but the rate of increase of negative feedback slows as Re1 is increased further in value.

Now consider the situation where we remove C2 from the circuit. The Feedback factor is now equal to 1 + ((Re1 + Re2)/re). We can no longer increase negative feedback (and reduce distortion) by increasing Re1 (or Re2 for that matter) and this is because increasing Re1 or Re2 causes a corresponding increase in the value of re leaving the feedback factor, 1 + ((Re1 + Re2)/re) unchanged. Thankfully in this situation the negative feedback is much higher than in the grounded emitter (Re2 bypassed and Re1 = 0 ohms
) situation creating much less distortion (much less variation in the value of re as Vin swings up and down).

In this situation where there is no by-passed emitter resistance, the way to increase negative feedback is to increase the base bias voltage. This reduces re (because Ie is increased) and therefore the feedback factor which is equal to 1 + ((Re1 + Re2)/re = dVin/dVbe is increased.